# Forgot password not working for .NET Core 3.x and React scaffold

Tags: reactjs, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-3.0

I have a project in .NET Core 3.1 and the frontend with React.

It was generated using the scaffold instructions from this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

When I try to trigger forgot password action, it shows a success page but there's no email being sent. The email exists in the database under the `AspNetUsers` table.

What could be wrong?

Some screenshots for reference.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the values of NormalizedEmail and EmailConfirmed in AspNetUsers.
If the value of NormalizedEmail is null or the value of EmailConfirmed is false, the email may not be sent
By default, the Send Complete screen is displayed even if the email has not been sent.
You also need to add an EmailSender in startup.cs.

[Send email with .NET Core 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58730594/send-email-with-net-core-2-2) ...

Comment: Thanks! The reason this was not working was because there was no `EmailSender` class declared, and then also added to `Startup.cs`